# New to haskell and I'm getting this error when I compile this in ghci, can figure out why. Everything seems to be right

Tags: haskell

```
n = a `div` length xs
where 
   a = 10
   xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is the error message i got

```
test.hs:27:8: parse error on input `xs'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I've tried renaming the 'xs' to a different name but it doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: This is just an indentation issue.

Comment: and where is that causing the problem?

Comment: Indent `where` more.

Answer (score 2):

As @leftaroundabout says: this is just a problem with the way you've indented the code. Here is a working version:

```
n :: Int
n = a `div` length xs
  where a = 10
        xs = [1..5]

main :: IO ()
main = print n    -- => 2
```

Indentation in Haskell is actually (for the most part¹) very intuitive.

> **The golden rule of indentation.**
>   Code which is part of some expression should be indented further in than the beginning of that expression (even if the expression is not the leftmost element of the line).

¹There is one little confusing exception, to do with placing an `if` statement in a `do` block (but you hardly ever have to worry about this). Look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#if_within_do) for more info.

Source: Haskell Wikibook, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#The_golden_rule_of_indentation

Comment: Ok, your way seemed to work but why can I have 'where' on its own line?

Comment: @carl123; It's just a stylistic thing: I like to save space by putting the first declaration on the same line as `where` – but as long as you align all the declarations Haskell doesn't mind.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. Thanks

Comment: @carl123; if the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it.

Comment: Yes it solved the problem and how do I go about accepting it?

Comment: @carl123; There should be a grey tick next to the answer. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).